# Printing on Epson receipt printers from Windows 10 command line

Tags: printing, controls, epson, receipt, escpos

I expect it to be possible to simply compose a notepad textfile with text and control chararcters (ESC/POS) and copy that file to an Epson Thermal Receipt printer. Amongst a lot of information that I found on internet, I could not find a sample text file that simply shows how to do such.
I was able to link the USB printer to lpt1 and when I use something like copy /b c:\test.txt lpt1, I get some output. I reached the printer but it doesn't understand the language so to speak.

I did find Epson documentation with the esc codes. It would be of great help if I had a sample text-file and some directions on how to place the control characters in that file.
The Epson information is not a course, it is a manual. That is why I get stuck I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the ESC/POS specifications based on this page.
[TOP»POS › TECH.REFERENCE»ESC/POS COMMAND FOR TM PRINTER»Introduction](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=2)

There is no document compiled in PDF etc., but perhaps it may be available by registering for EPSON's partner program. At least you can ask if it exists.
[Epson Advantage Partner Program](https://epson.com/epson-partners-program)

LPT devices may also be used for questions like questions, but a more suitable one would be serial port device mode.
If you change the interface setting of the printer hardware from the printer class to the vendor class and install the serial port device driver, you will be able to communicate via the serial port.
Please refer to the user's manual etc.

However, in any case, if there is no paper, the cover is open, or some error has occurred, printing will not be possible.
And you can't know the status just by sending unilaterally on the command line.

In order to deal with such a situation properly, it will be necessary to create a program that communicates with the printer and requests printing, and in that program, monitor the status of the printer and deal with errors.

Comment: It is an USB printer. The name LPT1 came from an exemple on internet. I should have used somethinge else like 'EpsonReceiptPrinter'. I made it look like a parallel printer, but that is not the case.

As mentioned, I do reach the printer and it prints my text (for example 'Hello Epson'). I do however not know how to put control-characters in such a text-file.
BTW I did try the ALT-keypad codes to put ascii-codes in, but that seems not to work. Maybe Notepad can't handle certain parts of the ascii-table. Or do I need to use another font?

Comment: The essence is the hardware mode setting, and the device name is secondary and insignificant. The parallel printer mode has a fixed usage and is less flexible. For creating and editing print data, it is better to choose a tool that can easily edit both binary data and text data instead of a text editor.